# There was an error managing chromedriver public (For input string: "public")

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

`Hello,
Using webDriverManager, when my chrome browser is updated I have the next ERROR :

```
`874  [main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager  – There was an error managing chromedriver public (For input string: "public")
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "public"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager.buildUrl(ChromeDriverManager.java:177)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager.buildUrl(ChromeDriverManager.java:154)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.download(WebDriverManager.java:1262)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:1183)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.fallback(WebDriverManager.java:1430)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:1408)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:1189)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:426)
    at fr.sihm.tnr.selenium.Browser.browserLaunch(Browser.java:105)`
```

In my resolution.properties file I have

```
`#WebDriverManager Resolution Cache
#Thu Mar 07 08:43:33 CET 2024
chrome=123
chrome123=**public**
chrome-ttl=09\:43\:33 07/03/2024 CET
chrome123-ttl=15\:46\:23 07/03/2024 CET`
```

and I need to change to

```
`#WebDriverManager Resolution Cache
#Thu Mar 07 08:43:33 CET 2024
chrome=123
chrome123=**123.0.6312.22**
chrome-ttl=09\:43\:33 07/03/2024 CET
chrome123-ttl=15\:46\:23 07/03/2024 CET`
```

before the file was updated automaticaly with the version and not with "public"`

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest WebDriverManager version (5.7.0 at the time of this writing) and clearing the cache (at least once) should fix this issue:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
```

See: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1239